# I want to create new column based on existing old column using multiple conditions how to do that

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, if-statement

imagine i have a column days

| days |
| --- |
| 190 |
| 567 |
| 55 |

I want to create a new column based on the condition that
df['new_colum'] =

```
if day < 180:
 print(y)
elif( days >180 & < 365):
 print(d)
else:
 print(h)
```

how do i do this in python and any alternative for if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.apply`:

```
df['new_col'] = df.days.apply(lambda x: y if x < 180 else (d if  180 < x < 365 else h))
```